# What is the “maximal hyperreal field”?

Tags: extension-field, model-theory, online-resources, nonstandard-analysis, surreal-numbers

In many SE posts and [the Wikipedia article on the surreal numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) I’ve seen references to a “maximal” hyperreal field that’s isomorphic to the surreals. If they’re isomorphic, then why is it that hyperreal analysis is just as strong as real analysis, but surreal analysis doesn’t even have a functioning exponential function? I’ve also read that there’s another maximal field that has the surreals as a subfield, but I might be misremembering as I’ve also read that the surreals have every other ordered field as a subfield, but I’m not sure of that either.

Could the aforementioned maximal field be enriched by another ultra power construction to produce another field with the former as a subfield?

In [Repeated transfer principle for transfinite induction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489097/repeated-transfer-principle-for-transfinite-induction), I read that the ultra power construction of the hyperreals could be repeated an ordinal amount of times to produce another hyperreal field, but does this hold in the “limit” and produce a proper class sized field with the transfer principle, and if so, is it the same as the one mentioned in the Wikipedia article?

I guess I’ve read a bunch of conflicting things and want an answer, but I’d also like resources to read up on to better grasp these concepts as I can’t find any direct sources mentioning this maximal field, ordinally repeated ultrapowers, or the potential field that subsumes the surreals.

Comment: hi Lave Cave. this isn't an answer to your question, but I'd just like to note that the meaning of the term "hyperreal field" is not universally agreed upon. for example, letting $\mathcal{R}$ be the structure expanding $\mathbb{R}$ with predicates for all functions and relations on it, I believe I've seen all of the following referred to as hyperreal fields: (i) the non-trivial ultrapowers of $\mathcal{R}$, (ii) the non-trivial elementary extensions of $\mathcal{R}$, (iii) the `monster models' of $\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal{R})$, given your appropriate definition of monster model.

Comment: because the wikipedia article doesn't define what it means by "hyperreal field" the statement there could mean any number of things. presumably there's a specific theorem they're referring to but unfortunately they don't seem to cite any paper! seems like quite bad practice to me

Comment: one additional thing I will note. for any first-order theory $T$ with infinite models, one can prove the following in NBG set theory with the axiom of global choice: there is a class-sized "model" $\mathbb{M}\models T$ such that every type over any set-sized $A\subset\mathbb{M}$ is realized in $\mathbb{M}$. (I say "model" in quotation marks because the usual definition of model defines them as set-sized objects.) moreover one can prove this object is unique up to "isomorphism", in the sense of class functions

Comment: (for a reference see Chapter 6 of Tent and Ziegler's "Course in Model Theory".) as a model theorist, this is what I would consider the canonical "maximal" model of $T$. however, this is my own bias, and the wikipedia article again doesn't specify if this is what it means

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (note: from an enthusiast's point of view ‒ corrections are welcome!) is that while there is an isomorphism, it does not necessarily mean that everything is the same or behaves as expected ‒ it depends on the extent of the isomorphism, which does not even have to be unique or easily expressible. You can't even be sure that the hyperreal $\omega$ is the same as the surreal $\omega$, since, after all, isomorphism is all about *renaming*. As an analogy, take the $p$-adic numbers, $ℚ_p$, make them algebraically and Cauchy complete, and you end up with $ℂ_p$, which is isomorphic only *as a field* to $ℂ$, since you have to change the $p$-adic metric to the usual one. In addition, while you can distinguish two elements identifiable as $i$ and $-i$ in $ℂ_p$, they don't correspond uniquely to the usual ones in $ℂ$ ‒ they may be swapped, and so one has to be careful with something like order based on the imaginary part.

Something similar can be seen in the surreals (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Examples)): while you can define an extension of $e^x$ on the surreals, you end up with $\exp{\omega}=\omega^\omega$, and as an arbitrary exponentiation ($x^y=\exp{(y\log{x})}$), you would end up with $“\omega^\omega”=\exp{(\omega\log{\omega})}=\omega^{\omega^{1+\varepsilon}}\neq\omega^\omega$. While there may be an (ordered) field isomorphism, there are emergent operations depending on the deeper structure, and as a result, there are things behaving differently than on the hyperreals where everything is guaranteed by the transfer principle (thus $\exp{\omega}=e^\omega<\omega^\omega$). Then there is the matter of things like $\sin{\omega}$, somewhat arbitrarily existing in the hyperreals, but requiring complex reasoning to arrive at its value in the surreals, and when you show $\sin{\omega}=0$ there, the only way that would be possible in the hyperreals is if $\omega$ was a hypernatural multiple of $\pi$. It is obvious already such an isomorphism is not trivial, and per [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/a/91654), there might not be a "natural" one at all.

Comment: The point to remember here.  An isomorphism of ordered fields need not preserve exponentiation (when it exists).  Similarly, it need not preserve limits (when they exist).  Our familiar reals have structure that we like to use in addition to the "ordered field" structure.

Answer (score 0):

The main strength of the hyperreals is the existence of a [transfer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle#Transfer_principle_for_the_hyperreals), which is what makes the hypereals applicable in analysis and many other fields.  If the surreals can be said to possess a transfer principle at all, it is only by means of transplanting it from the hyperreals via an isomorphism.  See further [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418402/interpreting-conways-remark-about-using-the-surreals-for-non-standard-analysis/418591#418591).