# Are there guaranteed conglomerate sized models for a given first-order theory?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

In a comment under [What is the “maximal hyperreal field”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512969/what-is-the-maximal-hyperreal-field) a commenter put “for any first-order theory 
with infinite models, one can prove the following in NBG set theory with the axiom of global choice: there is a class-sized "model" ⊨
such that every type over any set-sized ⊂
is realized in 
. (I say "model" in quotation marks because the usual definition of model defines them as set-sized objects.) moreover one can prove this object is unique up to "isomorphism", in the sense of class functions”

Does the same theorem hold for the conglomerates of [Morse-Kelley Set Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory)? If so, is there any text that mentions them and can this be used to make an ordered field larger than the surreals but with the transfer principle?

Comment: What are conglomerates in the context of Morse-Kelley set theory?

Comment: @JamesHanson a conglomerate is to a class what a class is to a set: it’s a collection of classes which can be proper classes and there can be the conglomerate of all classes.

Comment: In order to get something like that to work, you're likely going to need to assume some kind of global choice for classes (i.e., that there is a definable well-ordering of classes).